# Azure DevOps Self host agent

Tags: azure-devops, azure-private-link

I'm building an hubspoke architecture in azure with private endpoints for PaaS. This means I might not be able to utilize the Microsoft-hosted agents for build and release pipeline. To this end, I want to use self-hosted agent. Can I deploy, an agent in the hub that can serve spokes PaaS from a release pipeline use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Create a "agent" subnet in your hub network and then add appropriate agents (either VM or container based depending on need) You'll need to ensure that your NSG's for outbound traffic on the hub subnets and inbound traffic on the spoke subnets are configured to allow traffic. The exact settings will depend on what protocols your using for deployment. (HTTP, SSH etc)